# Purpose of class = void in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, void

What is the purpose of the `class = void` in the following code snippets?

```
template< class, class = void >
struct has_type_member : false_type { };

template< class T >
struct has_type_member<T, void_t<typename T::type>> : true_type { };
```

Comment: it is a default for the parameter

Comment: it will work even without `class = void`, no?

Comment: @BЈовић No it won't.

Comment: @Barry Because it is called with 2 template arguments? The OP didn't put how it is used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
template< class, class = void >
struct has_type_member : false_type { };
```

That's your default struct template, it asks for 2 template arguments but the second one is set to `void` as default, so this argument does not need to be specified explicitly, somewhat like a default function parameter.

Then :

```
template< class T >
struct has_type_member<T, void_t<typename T::type>> : true_type { };
```

Is a template specialization for your `has_type_member` struct, SFINAE will rule out this specialization if `T::type` doesn't exist (and thus, is invalid syntax), if it does exist it will pick this specialization otherwise.

The 2nd parameter is necessary to be used for template specialization, but we don't use it in our "fallback" `struct` so we just default to `void`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, one could do `class = std::void_t<>` to hint at what goes on.

Comment: May I ask why `class = void` can't be omitted?

Comment: @laike9m you need the `class` so that it is a 2 parameter template, for the specialisation. You want the `= void` so that users of the template only pass the type they are interested in.